# Query URL without redirect in Go

Tags: redirect, go

I am writing a benchmark test for a redirect script.

I wisg my program to query certain URL that redirects to AppStore. But I do not wish to download AppStore page. I just wish to log redirect URL or error.

How do I tell Go to query URL without second redirect query?

---

**UPDATE**

Both answers are correct BUT:

I tried both solutions. I am doing benchmarking.
I run 1 or many go processes with 10 - 500 go routines. They query URL in a loop.
My server is also written in go. It reports number of requests every second.

- First solution: `http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip` - works slow, gives errors. 
  First 4 seconds works fine. Making 300-500 queries then performance drops to 80 query per second.

Then drops to 0-5 query per second and queryies script start getting errors like

```
dial tcp IP:80: A connection attempt failed because the connected 
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

I guess it re-use connection that is closed.

- Second solution: `CheckRedirect field` works with constant performance. I am not sure if it re-uses connections or it opens a new connection for every request. I create `client` for every request in a loop. It is how it will behave in a real life (every request is a new connection). Is there way to ensure that connections are closed after each query and not re-used?

That is why I am going to mark second solution as such that answer my question. But for my research it is very important that each query was a new connection. How can I ensure with second solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For completeness' sake, you *can* use an `http.Client` and not follow redirects. `http.Client` has a [`CheckRedirect` field](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) which is a function. It is called before following any redirection.

If this function returns an error, then `httpClient.Do(...)` will *not* follow the redirect (see [`doFollowingRedirects()` function in Go's source code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go?s=708:1583#L203)) and instead will return an error (its concrete type will be `url.Error`, and its `URL` field will be the redirect-to URL, aka the Location header value, [see this code](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/client.go?s=708:1583#L276)).

You can see my [gocrawl library](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/gocrawl/blob/master/ext.go#L120) for a concrete example of this use.

Comment: Thanks. Is there was to ensure that connection is closed after each request? I wish to simulate huge traffic from social network that must be re-directed in 1-5 minutes based on Agent header. So every user queries only once and must be redirected. (that is connection must be closed)

Comment: I'm not sure I would create a custom client for a load testing/benchmarking tool. I would suggest using something like Apache Bench (ab, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

Comment: I know ab. But I wish to know Go networking better. Such a trivial case course so many questions. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

You need to use an http.Transport instead of an http.Client. Transport is lower-level and does not follow redirects.

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/redirectToAppStore", nil)
// ...
resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
```