# Golang: how to make http client not following redirects?

Tags: http, go, session-cookies, http-redirect

I would like to make an http call using an http client with these characteristics:

- don't follow redirects (just get the full response of the first call, which returns a 302 redirect code)
- being able to receive cookies

Hence, I am looking for a solution with `http.Client` rather than with `trasport.RoundTrip`

how can I do that?

Comment: How to store cookies is a completely separate question from how to check the redirect response.

Comment: Yes, that's the tricky part. I could get the single response using transport.RoundTrip instead of an http client, but I am also looking for a solution that can retrieve the cookie.

Comment: Doesn't the CookieJar work when you use the http.Client, but stop on the first redirect?

Comment: yes, I am trying to find out how to not to make the client do redirects.

Comment: Possible duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297520/how-can-i-make-the-go-http-client-not-follow-redirects-automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420222/query-url-without-redirect-in-go

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a `http.Client`, you have the option of using the `CheckRedirect` [field](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client).

This field takes a custom function which can then handle any redirects if an error is received by the initial request.

A simple example might be something like this:

```
client: &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return errors.New("something bad happened") // or maybe the error from the request
    },
}
```

You could also return the `http.ErrUseLastResponse` [error](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/net/http/client.go#L423) which returns the most recent response with its body unclosed.

Comment: great! can you provide any sample code so that in case of response 302, the redirect is not followed?

Comment: @DanieleB - I've updated my answer to show a simple implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not really sure how this should be used. What I want is: 1) the client should not follow the redirect; 2) I would be able to get the redirect URL; 3) the CookieJar would work as usual

Comment: Ideally, it should be the equivalent of setting a "flag" on the client not to follow the redirect, and being able to inspect cookieJar and response, as usual

Comment: @DanieleB: error returned from CheckRedirect is the "flag"

Comment: I still don't understand how to use it.

Comment: @DanieleB : You use the client, not the error. 1) This client does not follow redirect. 2) Inspect the Location header to find out the redirect URL. 3) Cookie jar should work.

Comment: @Volker thanks. So, is it enough to return any kind of error in the CheckRedirect function in order not to follow redirects?

Comment: @DanieleB - would you accept my answer as correct? :)

Comment: I have just implemented it and it works great!
I have also realized that it is even possibile to modify the request of the following redirect, and hence change the redirected url. Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

```golang
    client := &http.Client{
        CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return http.ErrUseLastResponse
        },
    }
```

According to https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect